# React-router-dom Navigation to not working <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having trouble navigating to the checkout page. Whenever I click on the basket icon in the app, I can see that the URL is changing but the page is not, I always have to refresh the page for the navigation to happen and I am not sure why.

This is my code for App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route}
from "react-router-dom";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";

function App() {
  return (
    // BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Header />
            <h1>in checkout</h1>
            </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Header />
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am using these version of react:

```
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router": "^6.4.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

I tried changing the version of react router and it still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've conflicting versions between `react-router` and `react-router-dom`, and between `react-router-dom` and `react`.

Uninstall `react-router` since it's incompatible with the code you are using and the fact that `react-router-dom` already re-exports *all* of `react-router`.

```
npm un -s react-router
```

Then install *at least* `react-router-dom@5.3.3` so that the router/routing can work correctly with `react@18` and any `React.StrictMode` component you may be rendering the app into.

```
npm i -s react-router-dom@5
```

See my answer [here](/a/71833424/8690857) regarding routing issue between `react@18` and pre-5.3.3 versions of `react-router-dom`.